# in-order traversal of a binary search tree returning a list

Tags: python, list, recursion, binary-search-tree

I need to return an ordered list of references with an empty in between them after traversing a BST, but i can't workout how to do it.

```
def inorder(self, Node):

    res = ""
    if Node != None:

        self.inorder(Node.LeftChild())
        res = res +(Node.key + " " + Node.payload + "\n")
        self.inorder(Node.RightChild())

    return res
```

this is my code, so far i can only get one reference returned, any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: you process left branch and throw the result away. Same for right branch. Your method has a return value, use it.

Comment: thanks @Lesiak, i'm new at this, won't you be able to provide an example how to do it?

Comment: Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 1):

You almost had it right, just need to use the return value of the right and the left sub trees in your `res` variable

```
def inorder(self, Node):

    res = ""
    if Node != None:

        lres = self.inorder(Node.LeftChild())
        rres = self.inorder(Node.RightChild())
        res = lres + (Node.key + " " + Node.payload + "\n") + rres

    return res
```

Note: `res` was always empty string in your condition, so you did not need to do `res = res+`, also there is a shorthand notation for doing this `res+=` but you didn't need it anyway.